Do you use "frame somebody" or "set somebody up" in these 2 situations?
Situation 1, Bob was driving when he got stopped by a police officer. The police, then, opened the boot of the car and saw some drugs. Bob didn't know why the drugs got there.
Situation 2, A man killed a person with his gun. Then, he wiped off his fingerprints on the gun's handle. He put the gun on a table then called Bob to come to his place for a meal. Bob came and saw the gun on the table. The man asked Bob to pick up the gun and check it to see if it is good. Bob did as the man asked. A few days later, the police came and found Bob's fingerprints on the gun. Bob got arrested.
I heard "frame somebody" means they do not trick you but create a false evidence against you.
"set up somebody" means they do trick you into doing things that are used as a false evidence against you.
Do you use "frame somebody" or "set somebody up" in these 2 situations?

"I don't know how the drugs got there" normally is intended to mean "They are not my drugs. I have no knowledge of them or who put them in my car."  "I don't know why ..."is not quite idiomatic and may even suggest that they are his drugs.

No, there’s no difference between the two phrases.
Collins Dictionary sense 11 says

If someone frames an innocent person, they make other people think that that person is guilty of a crime, by lying or inventing evidence.

and sense 8 says

If you are set up by someone, they make it seem that you have done something wrong when you have not.

There’s no mention in the definitions
that set up has the extra component of the victim being tricked into doing something.
frame
set up

Oxford: A scheme or trick intended to incriminate or deceive someone; Cambridge: An action that deceives someone in order to profit or get an advantage:

Here's my American take on it:
Situation 2 is more aligned with framing somebody. When you frame somebody, the crime has usually already been committed, and you manufacture evidence or tamper with existing evidence to make it appear that someone else committed the crime, when it was really you. The gun and the fingerprints are a good example of that.
When you set somebody up, you're typically working with the police to enable them to catch someone in the act of committing a crime by staging it. For example, you buy drugs from a drug dealer and you get caught using them by the police. The police say they won't charge you if you agree to buy drugs from the same drug dealer wearing a hidden microphone so the police can gather their evidence and arrest the dealer. You are setting up the drug dealer to get arrested. The crime usually has to be a repeatable crime (such as buying drugs).
In Situation 1,  (BTW, it should be how the drugs got there, not why the drugs got there) it's not clear if either applies. If someone planted the drugs in Bob's car, it doesn't really make sense to say he's being framed because no crime has been committed yet. If someone either worked with the police to plant the drugs or planted the drugs and then called the police to say that Bob had drugs in his car, that could be a setup. But Bob doesn't know how the drugs got there, and we don't either. Perhaps someone dropped their drugs by mistake into Bob's car and Bob got caught with them. That would be something entirely different.

The two phrases can have the same meaning but set somebody up has the additional meaning of acting together with the police to catch someone committing a crime, a crime they repeatedly commit.

I don't know how those drugs got in my car. Somebody's trying to set me up.
I don't know how those drugs got in my car. Somebody's trying to frame me.
Mikey set me up. He wore a wire when we were planning our last heist.
Mikey framed me: misused  he wore a wire when we were planning our last heist.


I suggest that no, there is no difference. 'Framed…' and 'Set up… ' always mean exactly the same.

@RobbieGoodwin  I don't think you understood the answer.  Surely you don't think the final sentence is correct, the one I've marked as "misused" with superscript.  Cooperating with the police is not "framing" someone.  "Framing" someone involves planting evidence, not helping the police to collect it.

Thanks TimR and I suggest it's you who misunderstood.
I have no idea what your ' "misused" with superscript' meant but in no case could it change the simple fact that 'Framed…' and 'Set up… ' always mean the same.
If you truly doubt that, why not find some real-world examples to demonstrate the difference? The reason I can't do that is that are none.

@RobbieGoodwin You're wrong. There are times when you can use set up but not framed.  That is what the final sentence is indicating.  "Framed" is misused there. It should be "set up".  Perhaps you were thrown off by the fact that it's two sentences.  I'll change the punctuation.

Sorry TimR and still, it's you who are wrong. If you want to keep playing pots and kettles there is still no possibility that 'set up' and 'framed' could not be perfectly interchangeable. That remains why neither I nor anyone else can find a relevant example.
That's also the reason you can't find a mis-matching example but have to rely on repeating a view wholly unsupportable.
Clearly you don't like that and how much do your or my likes mean?
Please produce an example where 'set up' and 'framed' are not wholly interchangeable.
One, please?

@RobbieGoodwin We'll have to agree to disagree. Perhaps it's a transatlantic difference. Are you a BrE speaker?  In AmE, my final example is a misuse of the verb "to frame (someone)".  Cooperating with the police to let someone incriminate themselves on a recording is not "framing" them, on this side of the Atlantic.

@RobbieGoodwin "I just killed the royal heir to the throne. But wait a minute, where's my getaway vehicle? Oh no, my accomplices never planned to help me escape at all! I've been set up!" In my English dialect (AmE), you can't say I got framed, because while I was betrayed, I am not innocent.

But it is "setting them up".

@TimR You're right, but that's 45266's point. That point might even be right prolly right in strictest class-room theory, but even the screen world tends not to work so strictly.
If we had time to re-watch too many hours of factual or fictional film, does anyone doubt we would find no few instances saying people were framed, innocent or not.
Somewhere in the middle I suggest '… frame-up' even more than '… stitch-up' confuses the issue, though I don't recall an example
